# Spinner.js not spinning in my asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, spinner

I can't post all of my code but I will show the majority of it.

So, these are the snippets of my code that handle the spinner functionality.  It allows me to see the spinner but it does not spin.  I have some code that does the stop of the spinner also, but I have taken that out and it still doesn't spin it just shows the spinner frozen.  Any ideas?  I have been looking at this and I am unable to determine where my issue is.  Maybe it has something to do with using it in asp.net.  I also have the script for spinmin.js in my files but just not showing it here.

```
//aspx
<div id="waitDiv" class="divWait" ></div>

//css
.divWait { text-align: center; width: 950px; height: 190px; }

//javascript
var spinner;

function doSpinner() {
            var opts = createSpinnerOpts();
            var target = document.getElementById('waitDiv');
            if (typeof(spinner) == 'undefined') {
                spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
            }

}

function createSpinnerOpts() {
            var opts = {
                lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 7, // The length of each line
                width: 8, // The line thickness
                radius: 40, // The radius of the inner circle
                corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
                rotate: 89, // The rotation offset
                color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                speed: 0.5, // Rounds per second
                trail: 100, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: true, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: true, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
                zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
                top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
                left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };
            return opts;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am the fool for today.  Add in the spinner as the class and it will spin....

```
<div id="waitDiv" class="spinner" ></div>
```